# Reset Personal Campaign Amounts for Individual PCP

Tags: contribution-page, personal-campaign-pages

So I run a yearly Campaign that individuals raise money for - Rather than have them redo a new PCP page - How do I reset their contributions so they can just use the same page for the new year -

I was able to use profile to move all the contribution to a different contribution page for tracking - but they still show up in the PCP that uses the original contribution page

Thoughts 
Running Civi 5.8.1 on Joomla 3.9.3